# Downloading a file from a URL -- Nothing works

Tags: java, download

I run a Minecraft server for my friends, and a while back I very shoddily put together an installer which would download mods and install them properly to the correct location.

After about 6 hours of figuring out how to do what I was trying to do, I successfully got a working installer. I tried it again today, and found that it has stopped working. I've been trying to fix it, but to no avail. I cannot find any solution which actually gets the whole file to download, rather, an empty 4KB file is created. I tried on a different computer and the same thing happened. I'm running the latest version of Java.

This is the method I'm using to download the file. I have tried solutions using a `ReadableByteChannel`, but that yielded similar results, with a 1KB empty file.

```
    public void download(String filename, URL url) {
    try {
        String fileName = filename; 
        URL link = url;

        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(link.openStream());
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int n = 0;
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        while (-1 != (n = in.read(buf))) {
            out.write(buf, 0, n);
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
        byte[] response = out.toByteArray();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        fos.write(response);
        fos.close();

        System.out.println("Download complete!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Download failed, something went wrong!");
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong with the method above? I can't really wrap my head around how downloading the file works, else I'd troubleshoot it myself. Any methods I can find on Google are going about it in pretty much the same way.

```
Printing stack trace:
at Install.download(Install.java:93)
at Install.downloadFile(Install.java:41)
at Install.main(Install.java:106)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

**EDIT:** Problem solved, used a different file hosting site to host the file. Now I just need to figure out how I can update the file without changing the URL.

Comment: First you should print the stack trace if there is one. Also whatś the StringBuffer for? Have you tried downloading the file with curl to make sure the server works?

Comment: Does your code return with "Download complete!" or "Download failed..."?
In later case:
What does the Stacktrace of e tell you?

Comment: Are you behind any proxy ?

Comment: @Jeroen As it turns out, the server I was downloading from (Google Drive) apparently just isn't usable for what I'm trying to do. I put the file on a different hosting service and now it works just fine. Thanks!